# É possível obter uma linha específica de arquivo txt/csv usando um endereço?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, edi

É possível acessar uma linha de um arquivo `txt`/`csv` (exemplo abaixo) pelo seu endereço diretamente sem precisar percorrer cada linha usando C#?

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: O que você chama endereço de cada linha? É esse número aí no início? É garantido que ele está em ordem crescente como aparece neste trecho?

Comment: Exemplo: eu percorro o arquivo guardando a chave e a linha que ele se encontra (exemplo 5ª linha). depois tem alguma forma de eu ler o arquivo somente para pegar essa 5ª linha? Como se fosse um vetor onde eu posso acessar uma posição específica

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você quer mas se entendi certo você vai ler o arquivo de qualquer jeito e vai querer voltar em alguns pontos depois. Primeiro precisa ver senão é melhor colocar tudo na memória para não ter que acessar o arquivo de novo. Pode ser que seja uma solução melhor. Se não for, você pode guardar esses dados que você pegou na linha e ainda a posição do arquivo onde essa linha começa para poder acessar esse trecho do arquivo diretamente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode guardar esses dados que você pegou na linha junto com a posição do arquivo onde essa linha começa para poder acessar esse trecho do arquivo diretamente em momento posterior.

Ler uma posição específica do arquivo em C# use o [método `Seek()` da FileStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_IO_FileStream_Seek_System_Int64_System_IO_SeekOrigin_):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    fs.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Begin); //100 é a posição onde inicia a linha desejada
    byte[] buffer = new byte[200]; //nada garante que a linha não seja maior que 200
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, 200));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/SeekInStream.cs)

Isto garante o acesso randômico a qualquer parte do arquivo diretamente. O [SeekOrigin.Begin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.seekorigin?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) indica que a posição é relativa ao começo do arquivo, que no fundo acaba sendo a posição absoluta. É possível ler à partir da posição atual e ao contrário do final do arquivo.

Entenda por posição o *byte* do arquivo em sequência.

Comment: Obrigado!!, é isso que estou precisando.

Comment: Eu tenho a ligeira impressão de que a posição no `FileStream` diz respeito a um cursor e não a uma linha, não?

Comment: Sim, e qual é o problema? Eu não falei em pegar a centésima linha, e sim a centésima posição.

Comment: Acho que o 1o paragrafo trata disso "dados que você pegou na linha junto com a posição do arquivo onde essa linha começa para poder acessar esse trecho do arquivo diretamente em momento posterior."

Comment: PEBKAC. Falha de interpretação de texto de minha parte XD

Comment: @Renan normal, faço sempre isso também.