# Como fazer pesquisa binária em um arquivo txt?

Tags: c#, java, arquivo, estrutura-de-dados, busca-binária

Estou com um arquivo txt que armazena dados de vários livros (exemplo abaixo) gostaria de fazer uma **pesquisa binária** que retorne a linha que estiver com o primeiro campo (ISBN do livro) equivalente a busca, sem carregar todo o arquivo na memória (considerando que o arquivo pode ter um tamanho muito grande) é possível fazer este tipo de pesquisa? Em C# ou Java.

OBS.: As linhas tem tamanho variado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode garantir que estes números no início de cada linha estão em ordem crescente? Pelo que você mostrou não estão. Aí não tem como.

Comment: Desculpe vou alterar o print, sim eles já estão ordenados.

Comment: Mas você mostrou que isto não é garantido.

Comment: Criei ja um método para ordenar, ai eu chamo o método, depois vou realizar a pesquisa binária, é que tinha mandado o print antes de chamar o método de ordenação. Agora está certo.

Comment: Mas se você varre todo o arquivo para fazer a ordenação, porque não joga isto em um banco de dados?

Comment: Acontece que é uma atividade da faculdade, tenho que trabalhar somente com arquivos.. tenho que fazer uma pesquisa binária nele. Se o tamanho das linhas fossem fixos eu conseguiria fazer. Gostaria de saber como fazer a pesquisa binária quando as linhas do arquivo (os registros) não tem tamanho fixo.

Comment: Vou descrever um algoritmo básico ou tentar fazer um pseudo código então, aí você codifica certinho.

Comment: Ok, ja vai ajudar muito!

Comment: Se tiver alguma dúvida, comente lá na resposta, mas se tiver dúvidas mais específicas de como fazer alguma operação em especial, talvez seja melhor abrir uma pergunta nova com a dúvida, caso contrário, esta pergunta ficaria muito ampla.

Comment: @williamhk2 você não pode indexar as linhas nessa ordenação? Seria legal ao ordenar, aproveitar e guardar a posição dos começos das linhas num outro txt ou mesmo na memória. Assim daria pra fazer a conversão numero da linha x posição na hora da busca.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vou descrever o que você precisa fazer, se der, mais tarde eu tento escrever algum código. Mas já adianto que não dá para fazer da forma mais precisa porque suas linhas não têm tamanho fixo. Então você tem que fazer mais ou menos o que um banco de dados faz, com a diferença que o banco de dados organizou os dados para isto.

Você já aprendeu como acessar o arquivo randomicamente na [sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37285/101).

Você precisará saber o tamanho do arquivo, algo como `System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length`. [Veja a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_IO_FileInfo_Length).

Você também precisará no [`Indexof()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#overloads) para achar a [quebra de linha](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Environment_NewLine).

## Estratégia de busca

Como não pode ler tudo para a memória terá que ler em páginas de dados. Minha sugestão é que estas páginas tenham 4096 *bytes*. É o tamanho da página de memória atualmente e o provável tamanho da página de de dados (*cluster*) em disco. Então ler e guardar um tamanho menor que isto será desperdício porque este é o tamanho mínimo que será lido fisicamente no disco. Com tamanhos menores você acabará lendo mais de uma vez os mesmos dados. É verdade que nas próximas vezes o sistema operacional provavelmente pegará do *cache* e não do disco. Esse tamanho nem fará *cosquinha* na memória, afinal depois de terminar de usar esse *buffer* ele poderá ser descartado pelo GC.

Dividindo o tamanho total do arquivo pelo tamanho do *buffer* você encontrará a quantidade páginas existentes no arquivo.

Você irá ler essas páginas que certamente conterá várias linhas (pelo padrão que você mostrou, não estou dizendo que é garantido que terá, mas parece que sim).

Já que você não tem como definir o tamanho das linhas você vai trabalhar com a páginas e aplicará a busca binária nas páginas que funcionarão como o elemento básico de procura.

Provavelmente você lerá a primeira página (conforme indicado na outra pergunta que respondi), a última, a do meio e depois sucessivamente irá ler a metade da metade atual indo para a metade anterior ou posterior conforme a comparação.

Como você chega na página. Pense nas páginas numeradas de zero até a última menos um. Por exemplo, se tiver 20 páginas, elas serão numeradas de 0 à 19. E o início de cada página é seu número vezes o tamanho. A primeira será 0 X 4096, ou seja, posição 0 do arquivo. A página 10 será 10 X 4096 e ela deverá começar ser lida na posição 40960. Sempre vai ler 4096 *bytes* seguintes, conforme o tamanho do *buffer*. Não importa que a última provavelmente não terá todo *buffer* preenchido.

Em cada página lida você vai ter que procurar por todos os códigos ISBN. Pelo que entendi, ele vem sempre depois de uma quebra de linha, então vai procurar com `IndexOf()` pelo(s) caractere(s) de quebra de linha. Aí é pegar os 14 caracteres seguintes. Este é o ISBN. Aí você compara com o que está procurando. isto será um *loop* para achar todas as quebras de linha e consequentemente o código que vem logo em seguida. Dentro da página provavelmente é melhor deixar a busca binária de lado e fazer a busca sequencial. Como dica saiba que existe [`IndexOf()` com *offset*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_) para fazer a busca de uma posição intermediária, ou seja, achar uma *string* começando em uma posição específica.

Se qualquer um for igual, você achou e pode encerrar o algoritmo da busca (falta só pegar toda a linha). Se o último código achado dentro da página for menor que o que procura vai procurar na meta posterior. Se o primeiro código achado dentro da página for maior do que está procurando, vai procurar na metade anterior. Se já olhou em todas as páginas possíveis (não existem mais páginas entre a atual e a última lidas) e não achou em nenhuma página, o código não existe.

Existe a possibilidade de um código começar nesta página e terminar só na outra. Você vai ter que analisar isto e se detectar que o código não está completo ler a próxima página em disco para pegar o resto do código.

Isto é o que você provavelmente terá que fazer também quando achar a linha que você quer. Existe uma probabilidade razoável de que a linha que você quer e achou está iniciando em uma página, mas ela só termina (ou seja, tem outra quebra de linha) na outra página, então tem que ler a outra página para ter a linha por completo.

Tudo o que eu descrevi é o processo de busca binária, nenhum segredo. O que tem de diferente é a estratégia de busca por páginas para dar uma informação estável de quebra de partes do arquivo.

## Conclusão

Percebe-se que isto não é o ideal, mas dadas as circunstâncias esta é a solução possível. Não entrei em tantos detalhes, pode ter algumas coisas que podem ser feitas de uma forma melhor, algumas verificações extras. Para fazer um exercício, é mais ou menos isso, para pôr em produção tem que arquitetar melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: OK vou tentar fazer desta maneira, se achar uma solução melhor eu postarei aqui. Obrigado!!

Comment: @williamhk2 dei uma reestruturada na resposta. Acho que assim fica mais claro, é mais fácil e dá um resultado melhor em performance. Vai falando aí se precisa de mais ajuda.

Answer (score 9):

A melhor abordagem para uma busca em arquivo texto vai depender da frequência com que o arquivo é modificado, do tempo necessário para percorrer o arquivo e do uso da funcionalidade de busca.

Dependendo do tamanho do tempo de leitura do arquivo, uma busca binária pode ser ineficiente no sentido de que não fará bom uso da CPU e do sistema de *buffer* e leitura do meio em questão. Nem toda leitura randômica ou aleatória é realmente sem custo. Ver [artigo](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/6/13/busting-4-modern-hardware-myths-are-memory-hdds-and-ssds-rea.html).

## Indexação

Se o arquivo não for atualizado com frequência, você pode criar um índice em memória que mantém as posições de cada linha vinculadas ao ISBN.

Veja um exemplo simples em Java:

```java
//lê e mantém um índice do ISBN
static class IndiceArquivo {

    //posição da linha
    static class PosicaoLinha {
        long inicio;
        int tamanho;
        PosicaoLinha(long inicio, int tamanho) {
            this.inicio = inicio;
            this.tamanho = tamanho;
        }
    }

    //índice
    Map<String, PosicaoLinha> indicePorIsbn = new HashMap<>();

    //arquivo
    Path arquivo;

    //construtor
    IndiceArquivo(Path arquivo) {
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
        montarIndice();
    }

    //lê todos os ISBNs
    void montarIndice() {
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(arquivo, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
            String linha;
            long posicao = 0;
            while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                indicePorIsbn.put(linha.substring(0, linha.indexOf('-')), new PosicaoLinha(posicao, linha.getBytes().length));
                posicao += linha.getBytes().length + System.getProperty("line.separator").length();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao ler o arquivo!");
        }
    }

    //encontra a posição indexada da linha do livro e então recupera a linha completa do arquivo
    Optional<String> getLinhaIsbn(String isbn) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(isbn)
                .map(k -> indicePorIsbn.get(k))
                .map(p -> {
                    try {
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(p.tamanho);
                        Files.newByteChannel(arquivo).position(p.inicio).read(buffer);
                        System.out.println(new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8"));
                        return new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao ler o arquivo!");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

E para testar:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //cria arquivo de exemplo
    Path arquivo = Files.createTempFile("meu", "teste");
    Files.write(arquivo, (
                    "123456789-titulo 1-autor 1-2012" + System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "234567890-titulo 2-autor 3-2013" + System.getProperty("line.separator") +
                    "345678901-titulo 3-autor 3-2014"
            ).getBytes("UTF-8"));

    //monta o índice
    IndiceArquivo indice = new IndiceArquivo(arquivo);

    //faz busca e verifica resultado
    Optional<String> resultadoBusca = indice.getLinhaIsbn("234567890");
    if (resultadoBusca.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Encontrou: " + resultadoBusca.get());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nao Encontrou");
    }
}
```

## Lendo tudo

Se o arquivo não for realmente tão grande e a leitura do arquivo não for necessária com muita frequência, simplesmente leia o arquivo todo usando um *stream*:

```java
static Optional<String> buscarIsbn(String isbn) throws Exception {
    Path arquivo = Paths.get("/meu/arquivo/grande.txt");
    String inicioLinha = isbn + "-";
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(arquivo)) {
        return lines.filter(linha -> linha.startsWith(inicioLinha)).findFirst();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao ler o arquivo!");
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Optional<String> resultadoBusca = buscarIsbn("1234567890");
    if (resultadoBusca.isPresent()) {
        //encontrou
    } else {
        //não encontrou
    }
}
```

## Cópia do arquivo alinhado

Outra alternativa é fazer uma cópia do arquivo com os caracteres alinhados, assim a busca binária pode ser feita com facilidade:

```java
static void alinharArquivo(int tamanhoMaximoLinha) throws Exception {
    Path arquivoOriginal = Paths.get("/meu/arquivo/grande.txt");
    Path arquivoAlinhado = Paths.get("/meu/arquivo/grande-alinhado.txt");
    try (
            Stream<String> linhas = Files.lines(arquivoOriginal);
            PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(arquivoAlinhado))) {
        linhas.forEachOrdered(l -> saida.format("%s-" + tamanhoMaximoLinha + "s", l));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao ler o arquivo!");
    }
}
```

## Considerações

Se uma funcionalidade depende de uma grande quantidade de dados, sendo crítica para o usuário e frequentemente usada, a melhor saída é considerar a migração para um banco de dados ou tecnologia adequada.

Caso a dependência de arquivos texto seja necessária, outra possibilidade seria dividir o arquivo logicamente em grupos, assim você consegue limitar a quantidade de informações pesquisadas em uma busca. Por exemplo, se dividir o arquivo grande em dez arquivos menores de acordo com alguns dos primeiros dígitos do ISBN, em cada busca seria possível determinar qual o arquivo a ser pesquisado e assim ignorar os outros 9.

Entretanto, considere também que qualquer solução como essa tem possibilidade de criar severas limitações no futuro. Por exemplo, se for necessário buscar por autor você ainda terá que percorrer os dez arquivos.

Portanto, eu diria que em linhas gerais a melhor abordagem é usar um banco de dados e a segunda melhor é utilizar um índice. Caso o índice seja muito grande para a memória, você poderia usar outro arquivo para armazená-lo com formato posicional de forma que fosse viável fazer uma busca binária.